# Videos on Raspberry Pie Android TV Videoview colored blue and very slow, other devices colors ok

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-videoview

Its incredible how slow Videos play with the VideoView and played from SD.
Is it possible to use Pie with android TV as a mediaplayer or is it justa not real working prototype os. Other mini PCs better?